# Does the SymPy function integration_steps reveal the result if the integration?

Tags: sympy

I'm using the SymPy function `integral_steps` to build a tool that, just like SymPy Gamma, reveals the integration steps when you ask it to integrate a function. My work-in-progress is available at https://lem.ma/1YH.

What I can't quite figure out is how to obtain the result of applying a particular rule. For example, consider the substitution rule

```
URule(u_var=_u, u_func=sin(x), constant=1, substep=ExpRule(base=E, exp=_u, context=exp(_u), symbol=_u), context=exp(sin(x))*cos(x), symbol=x)
```

The `context` field tells that the function being integrated is exp(sin(x))*cos(x) and that the rule uses a particular substitution - but what's the result of the integration so I can report to the user the same way SymPy Gamma does it. What I currently do is call `integrate` at every step, but that seems quite inefficient.

Perhaps there's an option that one can pass to integral_steps to make that information available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SymPy Gamma is open source as SymPy itself. Looking at its module [intsteps](https://github.com/sympy/sympy_gamma/blob/master/app/logic/intsteps.py) I see lines like

```
self.append("So, the result is: {}".format(
    self.format_math(_manualintegrate(rule))))
```

So, the way to obtain the outcome of a rule from the rule is to call `_manualintegrate(rule)`, which needs to be imported as

```
from sympy.integrals.manualintegrate import _manualintegrate
```

I imagine reading the rest of `intsteps.py` will be useful as well.